# Peace Lily - Black spots on flower

Tags: peace-lily

I have this Peace Lily which recently got this black spots on its flower, and also some leaves are becoming yellow. Do you guys have any idea of what may be happening? I water it regularly and the temperature here stays between 18-28 Celsius (64F-82F). I leave it indoors in my bedroom and I let it next o the window in the morning to get some light, and then I take it back to a shady area. There is a chemical industry near my house, not sure if this is related to it somehow. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Spathiphyllum (peace lily) does not appreciate direct sunlight, even through a window - keep it in a sunless but reasonably well lit (by daylight) spot - the black edges and blackened area on the white spathe are likely a result of sunlight exposure. However,in the first picture, that looks like a dusty black deposit, possibly of fungal origin - does it brush off? Check the rest of the plant, especially near the base, for signs of fungal growth - if everything's okay, it might just be the spathe/flower starting to fade, coupled with sun exposure (if it gets sun through that window).

Comment: These flowers look very old and are starting to decompose.  CUT the flowers off, use them in vases.  This will only help the plant as all that energy going into making flowers and seed will be diverted to the entire plant.  Cut as low as you can so there isn't a stump left.